# ¿Que son estas ediciones de preguntas?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, eliminación-de-preguntas

Estuve viendo varias ediciones a preguntas al estilo de esta:
[EDITADO EDITADO EDITADO EDITADO EDITADO EDITADO EDITADO EDITADA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98306/editado-editado-editado-editado-editado-editado-editado-editada), en principio pensé que era algún tipo de vandalismo y revertí algunas ediciones, pero luego me dí cuenta que es el propio OP el que aparentemente está haciendo estas modificaciones. ¿Que deberíamos hacer en estos casos? digo la pregunta con la edición mencionada pierde completamente el sentido y obviamente las eventuales respuestas también. ¿Puede ser considerado vandalismo cuando es el mismo OP el que realiza estos cambios?

Comment: Creo que no hay mucho por hacer, lo que hiciste es lo único que queda dentro de nuestro alcance y considero que estuvo muy bien. En el mejor (o el peor) de los casos un moderador puede eliminar la publicación y si llegara a ser una conducta recurrente el usuario puede quedar suspendido o baneado de por vida tras una segunda advertencia.

Comment: ¡Repórtalo a los moderadores! Ellos tienen herramientas para contactar con el usuario y/o hacer esta tarea más fácilmente.

Comment: Gracias @Flxtr..

Comment: @fedorqui, si tambén lo reporté y por las dudas revisé si había alguno en el chat..

Comment: La pregunta que voy a realizar puede ser estúpida o tener respuesta evidente, pero ¿podría ser válido si otra persona republicara la pregunta? ¿alguna forma de probar que el código no le "pertenece" al nuevo OP? Simplemente lo digo por quienes invirtieron algo de tiempo en responder.

Comment: @Shaz Es inconcebible que Stack Overflow acepte contenido sobre el cual no hay certeza de que sea legal publicarlo. A ninguna empresa le gusta ese tipo de riesgos legales.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos En el punto 3 de los [términos de uso del SO](https://stackexchange.com/legal) se indica que el usuario debe tener propiedad o derecho sobre los contenidos publicados y que se comparte bajo licencia Creative Commons. SO (o los moderadores) no tiene poder/conocimiento legal para decidir si algo publicado tiene copyright o no, pero estoy seguro que SO no tendría problema en eliminar contenido si una empresa llegara demostrando que el código de una pregunta/respuesta es propiedad suya.

Comment: Lo que ocurrió en este caso es que un usuario, al darse cuenta de que podría haber complicaciones al compartir código corporativo, decidió eliminar sus preguntas indiscriminadamente. Esto se considera vandalismo y va en contra de las normas del sitio. Una vez pasada la inquietud inicial (todos nos pondríamos nerviosos si pensásemos que nuestro empleo está en juego), nos pusimos en contacto con el usuario, le explicamos la situación, revisamos las publicaciones, y se recuperaron la mitad de las preguntas (intentando mantener las que tenían respuestas de usuarios).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ¡probablemente luciría más todo esto en una respuesta! Si no fuera por [la pregunta de Jose Antonio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2922/83) nunca habríamos leído tu comentario y, por tanto, sabido qué pasó con este tema.

Comment: @fedorqui estaba dudando entre comentario o respuesta... al final lo he puesto como los dos :$. Dime si se ve bien, o si debería recortar algo.

Comment: [off-topic] @PatricioMoracho, este post tenía las tags "java" y "script" cuándo tenía que ser "javascript"... no entiendo rechazar la sugerencia de edición cómo "no aporta nada" ?¿ https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/91106

Comment: @brasofilo, para estas cosas está el chat, cualquier cosa me ubicas allí. Saludos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El usuario logro eliminar la mayoria de las preguntas. En las ultimas ediciones escribio que el no poseia los derechos sobre el codigo, y que su jefe le habia pedido que eliminara las preguntas, o su puesto de trabajo corria peligro.

Reverti ediciones hasta que elimino las preguntas.

Es vandalismo porque OP acepta los terminos y condiciones, y hay respuestas de personas que se tomaron el trabajo de entender la pregunta y contestarla.

OP no puede poner como excusa del vandalismo eso. Si no hubiera podido eliminar las preguntas, deberia haber preguntado que hacer aca (en meta)

Comment: Es entendible la situación del OP, pero efectivamente eliminar las preguntas debiera ser la solución más "elegante". Es una lástima igual, por el trabajo y el tiempo que muchos se toman para responder, todo ese conocimiento se perderá.. como lágrimas en la lluvia.. ;-)

Comment: Cuando una persona tiene la obligación legal de hacer todo lo que esté en su mano para eliminar una pregunta/respuesta no es vandalismo el hacer todo lo que esté en su mano. Si hubiese estado en la misma situación yo hubiese 1.- Editado para ocultar hasta donde soy capaz el contenido que yo no tengo derecho a publicar y que SO tampoco tiene derecho. 2.- Eliminarlas y reportarlas pidiendo su borrado definitivo y explicando el motivo. 3.- Contactar a un moderador con las explicaciones oportunas.  --- Revertir ediciones a sabiendas de que es ilegal la publicación del contenido está mal.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, no tengo forma de darme cuenta de que una publicación es ilegal, aunque me lo diga el OP, no tengo forma. Lo único que puedo ver es una pregunta que fue totalmente vandalizada, sin ningún comentario de ninguna clase que me sirviera para tomar alguna decisión, puedo suponer que algún colega celoso le robo las credenciales y le está vandalizando su contenido, o como aparentemente pareciera ser, el dueño de la pregunta simplemente esta de alguna manera eliminando su contenido.

Comment: En lo que a mí respecta, para casos similares y resumiendo todos los comentarios: 1) El dueño de la pregunta puede hacer lo que quiera con ella, 2) Si aún siendo el dueño considero que hay un posible "vandalismo" lo reporto a los moderadores.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Pero sí tienes forma de darte cuenta de que una publicación es de dudosa legalidad cuando el autor original afirma que no es legal y el número de personas que afirma que es legal es igual a cero. ¿Permite Stack Overflow la publicación de contenidos de dudosa legalidad?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos la publicacion no era ilegal. El autor original del post dijo que sus jefes no lo dejaban publicar, que es distinto. Pero mas alla de eso, en lugar de eliminar las publicaciones, o comunicarse con un moderador, directamente cambio los posts. entonces no haiba forma de saber que pasaba. y cuando publicamos aca, cedemos derechos. Y dudo que SO se haga cargo de lo que se publica.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Tenía el autor original derecho a publicarlo? ¿Tenía una licencia que le permitiese publicarlo? Si la respuesta es no entonces es ilegal. Publicar algo violando los derechos de autor es ilegal. Y SO no tiene más remedio que ocuparse de lo que se publica, puedes ver por ejemplo [Who is responsible for copyrighted materials (publisher or writer)?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6136/who-is-responsible-for-copyrighted-materials-publisher-or-writer). Si SO actua con diligencia para resolver algo así no tendrá muchos problemas, pero no lo puede dejar estar.

Answer (score 6):

Otros usuarios han respondido las preguntas correctamente, así que voy a intentar explicar un poco qué es lo que sucedió, y dar un poco de información sobre el tema y cómo se gestionó.

---

**El problema**

Un usuario empezó a destruir su propio contenido porque podría contener material con copyright de su empresa (por miedo a ser despedido o a sufrir consecuencias legales).

---

**Qué se hizo**

Inicialmente se borró el contenido del usuario para poder revisarlo con más detenimiento. Esto podía o no haber ocurrido, pero la mayor parte del daño estaba ya hecho y se estaba entrando en una guerra de ediciones/reversiones que tampoco ayudaba a nadie.

Después, una vez pasada la inquietud inicial (todos nos pondríamos nerviosos si pensásemos que nuestro empleo está en juego), nos pusimos en contacto con el usuario:

- Le explicamos la situación (que se consideraba vandalismo e iba contra las normas del sitio);
- Revisamos las publicaciones (centrándonos en las que tenían respuestas);
- Editamos algunas de las preguntas para quitar "contenido problemático"; y
- Se recuperaron algunas de las preguntas.

En resumen: durante el incidente se eliminaron 9 preguntas, y de esas se recuperaron 5. Las otras 4 se quedaron eliminadas porque o contenían código que sería difícil eliminar (2), o eran duplicadas y no tenía sentido recuperarlas (2).

---

**Cómo evitar un incidente como éste**

Una solución simple: sólo publica el contenido que sepas que es tuyo. Si vas a publicar algo del trabajo, piensa dos veces antes de publicar cualquier código, y/o consulta con alguien dentro de tu empresa antes de hacerlo.

Y hay otra solución: **[crea ejemplos mínimos, completos y verificables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Si un fichero lanza un error, copia sólo la parte relacionada con el problema, no copies el contenido del fichero completo, más los ficheros de configuración, más la otra clase, más...

---

**Términos de uso**

En el punto 3 de los [términos de uso de Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/legal) se indica que el usuario debe tener propiedad o derecho sobre los contenidos publicados y que se comparte bajo licencia Creative Commons. **Es responsabilidad del usuario asegurarse de que lo que publica es legítimo**.

Comment: ¡Fantástico trabajo de seguimiento y explicación! Gracias por vuestro trabajo.

Comment: +1 al comentario de @fedorqui es genial saber con detalles qué pasó, qué medidas se tomaron y por qué.

Answer (score 1):

Ante estas situaciones es mejor:

- Votar negativamente a la pregunta/respuesta.
- Utilizar la opción **reportar** y seleccionar la opción:

> **Se necesita la intervención de un moderador**.